# How to assign a name to an empty excel column header using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a `Sub` which performs a `vlookup` for a whole column in Excel.

```
Option Explicit


Sub Vlookup() ' performs Vlookup of all entries in sheet1 with keys from sheet2

Dim wbk1 As Workbook

Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook ' wbk1 is master table

    With wbk1.Sheets("sheet1") 'define sheet in master table
       .Range("AA2:AA" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = _
       "=VLOOKUP(C2,sheet2!$A$2:$B$14,2,FALSE)" 'Actual vlookup
    End With

End Sub
```

The vlookup itself works well. However, the resulting column `AA:AA` lacks a header.

**How to assign a name (string) to an empty excel column header using VBA?**

Comment: how do you put a value into a cell? there are a lot of examples on the web. please do a search.

Comment: Do you mean `.Range("AA1").Value2 = "HeaderName"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check this:

Option Explicit

```
Sub Vlookup() ' performs Vlookup of all entries in sheet1 with keys from sheet2

Dim wbk1 As Workbook
Dim lastRow As Long


Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook ' wbk1 is master table

    With wbk1.Sheets("sheet1") 'define sheet in master table

    lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


       .Range("AA2:AA" & lastRow).Formula = _
       "=VLOOKUP(C2,sheet2!$A$2:$B$14,2,FALSE)" 'Actual vlookup
       .Range("AA1").Value = Sheet2.Range("b1").Value


    End With

End Sub
```